# How do I select only people who share last names? SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm still pretty new to working with databases, and this problem has me stumped.

I've got a People table with first and last name columns. I'm trying to create a query that will only select those who share last names with others in the table.

For example if I have these two columns:

```
First_Name      Last_Name
John            Doe
Jane            Doe
Mary            Shmo
Kate            Shmo
Matt            Diego
Joe             Smith
```

The result I want would be:

```
First_Name  Last_name
John        Doe
Jane        Doe
Mary        Shmo
Kate        Shmo
```

The code I have is:

```
select count(*), last_name, first_name 
from people
group by last_name
having count(*) > 1
```

This gets the shared last names, but only outputs one of each, instead of all the first names as well.

I'm sure there is a simple fix for this, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there. Now that you have the set of last names you care about, just wrap another query around that:

```
select * from people
where last_name in
(
    select last_name
    from people
    group by last_name
    having count(*) > 1
)
```

Comment: Thanks! Would it be to much to ask for you to explain how this works?

Comment: If you run that inner query, you'll see the last names that you care about. The outer query says "give me all people where the last name matches something from the inner query". There are a few other ways of doing that - inner joins like Barranka's answer, or `exists`, or probably more. I just like `in` because it's nice and clear what you're trying to accomplish, and the database optimizer probably translates it the same way anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a subquery to get this done:

```
select p.*
from people as p
     inner join (
                   select last_name 
                   from people 
                   group by last_name 
                   having count(first_name) > 1
                ) as a on p.last_name = a.last_name
```